# Nested borrows in match arms

Tags: rust, emulation, borrow-checker

I'm building a chip8 emulator where its structured like this:

```
pub struct Vm {
    pub cpu: RefCell<Processor>,
    pub memory: Rc<RefCell<Memory>>,
    pub keyboard: Rc<RefCell<Keyboard>>,
    pub display: Rc<RefCell<Display>>,
}

impl Vm {
    pub fn execute(&mut self, inst: u16) {
        let mut cpu = self.cpu.borrow_mut();
        let (nnn, nn, n, x, y) = cpu.decode_instruction(inst);
        let op = (inst & 0xF000) >> 12;

        match op {
            0x0000 => cpu.display_op(nn, self),
            0x1000 => cpu.jump_to_addr(nnn),
            0x2000 => cpu.call(nnn),
            0x3000 => cpu.skip_execution(inst, x, nn),
            0x4000 => cpu.skip_execution(inst, x, nn),
            0x5000 => cpu.reg_check_skip_exec(inst, x, y),
            0x6000 => cpu.set_reg_nn(x, nn),
            0x7000 => cpu.add_reg_nn(x, nn),
            0x8000 => cpu.alu_op(x, y, nn),
            0x9000 => cpu.reg_check_skip_exec(inst, x, y),
            0xA000 => cpu.set_i_to_addr(nnn),
            0xB000 => cpu.jump_to_addr_plus_offset(nnn),
            0xC000 => cpu.set_reg_rand(x, nn),
            0xD000 => cpu.draw_op(x, y, n, self),
            0xE000 => cpu.key_op(x, nn, self),
            0xF000 => cpu.timer_op(x, nn, self),
            _ => todo!()
        }
    }
}
```

the 4 functions which take self as a parameter in the match block borrow different components of the vm inside them, but when i try to compile this i get this error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/vm.rs:40:23
   |
35 |         let mut cpu = self.cpu.borrow_mut();
   |                       -------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
40 |             0x0000 => cpu.display_op(nn, self),
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
58 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow might be used here, when `cpu` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `RefMut<'_, Processor>`
```

the functions inside the CPU struct which take in a self are as follows, I've omitted the opcode implementation aspect of it for the sake of brevity:

```
pub(crate) fn display_op(&mut self, nn: u8, vm: &mut Vm) {
        let mut mem = vm.memory.borrow_mut();
}

pub(crate) fn draw_op(&mut self, x: u8, y: u8, n: u8, vm: &mut Vm) {
        let mut mem = vm.memory.borrow_mut();
}

pub(crate) fn key_op(&mut self, x: u8, nn: u8, vm: &mut Vm) {
        let keys = vm.keyboard.borrow();
}

pub(crate) fn timer_op(&mut self, x: u8, nn: u8, vm: &mut Vm)  {
        let mut mem = vm.memory.borrow_mut();
}
```

I've tried multiple different ways to solve this from passing the individual components in which seems to work (I do not know if it would function properly because my emulator is not yet at the stage where I can boot up a rom but it does compile) to trying a sort of bus architecture as one would see in a NES emulator which also failed spectacularly for similar reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by switching the parameter of `display_op()` (and `draw_op()`, etc.) from `&mut Vm` to `&Vm`. `Vm` already uses refcells in all fields, so you should be fine. For example, `vm.memory.borrow_mut()` compiles with `vm` being a `&Vm`.